# Multiple enemies get hit by arrow instead of one

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection, collider, projectile

I am working on my first Tower Defense game and I have a problem where multiple enemies get hit by a projectile instead of one.

Enemy with its collider:

[image: Enemy]

The problem is that when the enemies get close to each other, their colliders overlap and one arrow deals damage to multiple units.

Arrow and Enemy both have trigger colliders 2D.

Code for Arrow.cs component:

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) {
    Enemy enemy = collision.GetComponent<Enemy>();

         if (enemy != null) {
             IDamagable damagable = enemy.GetComponent<IDamagable>();
             if (damagable != null) {
                 damagable.ReceiveDamage(DamageType.PHYSICAL, attackType, damage);
             } else {
                 Debug.Log("Unit is missing the IDamagable script");
             }
             Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Seems like collision detection and OnTriggerEnter2D is called in the same step and this function runs multiple times even if the game object is destroyed.

Comment: How I would handle it: Do not let physics take care of the problem. The arrow is just the visual representation. If it is too much recoding, your IDamagble could include a 4th parameter: target. only if the target matches with what the tower wanted to hit will damage occur/ arrow be destroyed

Comment: I'm really not sure, but one thing I would try is to check inside the callback if `this==null`. Seems absurd, but that is just [checking if the object has been marked as destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72072517/19592578). The thing is that MonoBehaviours don't immediately stop existing when you call `Destroy()`, so it's possible that multiple callbacks that are happening on the same physics step have already been queued up by the time you destroy the object, and they all end up executing anyways.

Comment: @Zibelas thanks!
The approach that you suggested worked, I just added this check inside `if (enemy != null)`

Comment: @TarasFityo you can post an answer yourself with the code that did the trick for you. Keep in mind you should assign a max life time to your arrows, in case enemy gets destroyed by a second tower beforehand. Or a workaround is to partially destroy it (hide the visuals and what would damage the main target and let the arrow hit the now invisible arrow)

Comment: @Zibelas thanks for the suggestion. Currently I just added a check for target enemy but I didn;t remove physics. I am not sure how to implement for example arrow getting stuck in enemy's body without the colliders, I would need to add some more calculation regarding if arrow reached enemy.

Comment: You can totally keep the colliders. What I meant with removing physics was for using it as the main logic of how the arrow works (but even that depends on the exact type of tower defense game, in one where you would have arced shots, unaimed shots or whatever, physics might be the easier way). Leaving the collider for detecting if arrow reached enemy is ok and using for sticking the arrow there.

Answer (score 2):

As I have target set during initialization

```
private GameObject targetEnemy;
private int damage;
private AttackType attackType;

public void Initialize(GameObject targetEnemy, int damage, AttackType attackType) {
    this.targetEnemy = targetEnemy;
    this.damage = damage;
    this.attackType = attackType;
}
```

I just had to add additional check if collision happened for taget enemy, not some enemy that was close to he target.

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) {
    Enemy enemy = collision.GetComponent<Enemy>();

    if (enemy != null && targetEnemy == collision.gameObject) {
        ...receive damage
    }
}
```

Comment: Little optimization: I would start with the check `targetEnemy == collision.gameObject` and only then obtain the `enemy` component. Checking two references for equality is cheaper than acquiring a component via GetComponent. And there is no need to acquire that component anyway when you already know that it's not the target you are looking for. And considering that you are apparently not doing anything with the `Enemy` component and only with the `IDamageable`, you might not even need to check for that component.

Comment: thanks @Philipp

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the suggestion to keep track of the target. What you can do instead is have some bookkeeping in the projectile about whether it already hit a target or not (a boolean field should do the job). And if it already has, then you can just short-circuit in the collision code and not apply damage.

So something like this:

```
private bool hasHitAnEnemy = false;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) {
    if(hasHitAnEnemy) { 
        return;
    }

    Enemy enemy = collision.GetComponent<Enemy>();

    if (enemy != null) {
         IDamagable damagable = enemy.GetComponent<IDamagable>();
         if (damagable != null) {
             damagable.ReceiveDamage(DamageType.PHYSICAL, attackType, damage);
             hasHitAnEnemy = true;
         } else {
             Debug.Log("Unit is missing the IDamagable script");
         }
         Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: One trouble with this is that you don't have a guarantee of the order the `OnTriggerEnter2D` messages get fired. The enemy on the "far" side could get hit "first" if the projectile ends up overlapping both in the same physics step.

Comment: Hi S. Tarık Çetin, thanks for your suggestion. DMGregory is correct, I think that just simply checking if target is the one that was hit should be enough.

Comment: @DMGregory Why would that matter? If it hits, it hits.

Comment: It looks strange if I shoot arrows at a group of enemies and the one at the back, farthest from my shooting position, is the one that dies. (This can also happen with the target-based check). The way to fix this would be a raycast or shape cast each physics step, to ensure the first target hit is the one that takes the damage.

Comment: @DMGregory I still don't understand your point. In order for an enemy to take damage, it needs to be hit. In order for it to be hit, it needs to be touching the projectile. It doesn't matter where its centre point is. Nothing would look weird in that case.

Comment: I think you're visualizing a case where the enemies are well separated compared to how far the arrow travels in a single physics step, or how wide the arrow's collider is. In a game where the enemies are small/tightly packed and the arrow is long and fast moving, then in a single physics step it could go from touching no enemies to touching a whole line of them. If we get unlucky and the enemy at the back comes first in processing order, it looks to the player like the arrow somehow tunneled through the targets in the front without hitting them to reach this more distant, blocked target.